# Terminal command to find lines containing a specific word?

Tags: linux, text, terminal

I was just wondering what command i need to put into the terminal to read a text file, eliminate all lines that do not contain a certain keyword, and then print those lines onto a new file. for example, the keyword is "system". I want to be able to print all lines that contain system onto a new separate file. Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`grep` is your friend.

For example, you can do:

```
grep system <filename> > systemlines.out
```

man grep and you can get additional useful info as well (ex: line numbers, 1+ lines prior, 1+lines after, negation - ie: all lines that do not contain grep, etc...)

If you are running Windows, you can either install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.org) or you can find a win32 binary for grep as well.

Comment: remember by default grep is case sensitive

Comment: you can use `grep -i` to make it case insensitive, but I do not believe that was a requirement.

Answer (score 4):

```
grep '\<system\>'
```

Will search for lines that contain the *word* system, and not system as a substring.

Answer (score 3):

below [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) command will solve ur problem

```
grep -i yourword filename1 > filename2
```

`with -i  for case insensitiveness`

`without -i for case sensitiveness`

to learn how grep works on ur server ,refer to man page on ur server by the following command

```
man grep
```

Answer (score -1):

grep "system" filename > new-filename

You might want to make it a bit cleverer to not include lines with words like "dysystemic", but it's a good place to start.

Comment: Note that grep's `-w` option will force the search expression to be a "whole word", that is, delimited by whitespace (including the beginning and end of the line).